# understanding output of strace of empty c program

Tags: linux, strace

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Given the above C program, I get the following the output using `clang test.c ; strace ./a.out`.

```
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], [/* 36 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1a06000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f785c40f000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=78590, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 78590, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f785c3fb000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1840928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3949248, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f785be2a000
mprotect(0x7f785bfe5000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f785c1e4000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ba000) = 0x7f785c1e4000
mmap(0x7f785c1ea000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f785c1ea000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f785c3fa000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f785c3f8000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f785c3f8740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f785c1e4000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x600000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f785c411000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f785c3fb000, 78590)           = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Something puzzled me:

- What does line ending with `0x7f785c40f000` mean/do?
- Why is `3949248` in `mmap` when `libc.so` is `1840928` large?
- Where does the address used in `mprotect` come from?
- Where does the address used in `mmap` come from when it's not `NULL`?
- What are the 4k and 8k memory allocated by `mmap` right before `arch_prctl`?

Comment: Nice question. The above should pretty much all be the work of the dynamic loader, which is has quite a complex spec. It would be interesting to compare it with a `-static` build, where most of this stuff doesn't happen but other does (like a `uname` call and a few `brk` calls but no `mmap`s).

Comment: @PSkocik Yes, that's how it turned out: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15001856/

Answer (score 0):

Rather that try and tell you why those exact addresses/sizes are used (and since no one else has answered), I thought you might like a way to examine where the values come from.  You can use gdb on the loader and stop at each syscall, or a particular syscall.  Assuming you have debuginfos installed, you can look at the code to see the values.  Here's an example:

```
$ gdb -q /lib64/ld-2.17.so
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-2.17.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib64/ld-2.17.so.debug...done.
done.
(gdb) b _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1430
(gdb) run ./a.out
Starting program: /lib64/ld-2.17.so ./a.out

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555430 in _start ()
(gdb) p getpid()
$1 = 18102
(gdb) !cat /proc/18102/maps
555555554000-555555575000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396014                     /lib64/ld-2.17.so
555555775000-555555777000 rw-p 00021000 ca:01 396014                     /lib64/ld-2.17.so
555555777000-555555778000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
(gdb) catch syscall mmap
Catchpoint 2 (syscall 'mmap' [9])
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Catchpoint 2 (call to syscall mmap), 0x000055555556c6aa in mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81      T_PSEUDO (SYSCALL_SYMBOL, SYSCALL_NAME, SYSCALL_NARGS)
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  0x000055555556c6aa in mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81

Catchpoint 2 (returned from syscall mmap), 0x000055555556c6aa in mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81      T_PSEUDO (SYSCALL_SYMBOL, SYSCALL_NAME, SYSCALL_NARGS)
(gdb) !cat /proc/18102/maps
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 13014                              /home/ec2-user/so/e1/a.out
555555554000-555555575000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396014                     /lib64/ld-2.17.so
555555775000-555555777000 rw-p 00021000 ca:01 396014                     /lib64/ld-2.17.so
555555777000-555555778000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[...]
Continuing.

Catchpoint 2 (call to syscall mmap), 0x000055555556c6aa in mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81      T_PSEUDO (SYSCALL_SYMBOL, SYSCALL_NAME, SYSCALL_NARGS)
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  0x000055555556c6aa in mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81

Catchpoint 2 (returned from syscall mmap), 0x000055555556c6aa in mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81      T_PSEUDO (SYSCALL_SYMBOL, SYSCALL_NAME, SYSCALL_NARGS)
(gdb) !cat /proc/18102/maps
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 13014                              /home/ec2-user/so/e1/a.out
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 ca:01 13014                              /home/ec2-user/so/e1/a.out
555555554000-555555575000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396014                     /lib64/ld-2.17.so
555555775000-555555777000 rw-p 00021000 ca:01 396014                     /lib64/ld-2.17.so
555555777000-555555778000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7ffff7c32000-7ffff7ff4000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 396021                     /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7ffff7ff4000-7ffff7ffa000 r--p 00000000 ca:01 305615                     /etc/ld.so.cache
7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000055555556c6aa in mmap64 () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0x000055555555a45f in _dl_map_object_from_fd (name=name@entry=0x4002a1 "libc.so.6", fd=7, fbp=fbp@entry=0x7fffffffdb78,
    realname=0x7ffff7ffa640 "/lib64/libc.so.6", loader=loader@entry=0x555555777210, l_type=l_type@entry=1, mode=mode@entry=0,
    stack_endp=stack_endp@entry=0x7fffffffdb70, nsid=nsid@entry=0) at dl-load.c:1295
#2  0x000055555555c49b in _dl_map_object (loader=0x555555777210, name=0x4002a1 "libc.so.6", type=1, trace_mode=0, mode=<optimized out>, nsid=<optimized out>)
    at dl-load.c:2374
#3  0x0000555555560992 in openaux (a=a@entry=0x7fffffffe128) at dl-deps.c:63
#4  0x00005555555631b4 in _dl_catch_error (objname=objname@entry=0x7fffffffe120, errstring=errstring@entry=0x7fffffffe118,
    mallocedp=mallocedp@entry=0x7fffffffe110, operate=operate@entry=0x555555560960 <openaux>, args=args@entry=0x7fffffffe128) at dl-error.c:177
#5  0x0000555555561092 in _dl_map_object_deps (map=<optimized out>, preloads=<optimized out>, npreloads=<optimized out>, trace_mode=<optimized out>,
    open_mode=<optimized out>) at dl-deps.c:256
#6  0x00005555555572c5 in dl_main (phdr=<optimized out>, phdr@entry=0x555555554040, phnum=<optimized out>, phnum@entry=7,
    user_entry=user_entry@entry=0x7fffffffe2b8, auxv=<optimized out>) at rtld.c:1727
#7  0x000055555556a7d5 in _dl_sysdep_start (start_argptr=<optimized out>, dl_main=0x555555555a70 <dl_main>) at ../elf/dl-sysdep.c:244
#8  0x0000555555558cc1 in _dl_start_final (arg=0x7fffffffe370) at rtld.c:318
#9  _dl_start (arg=0x7fffffffe370) at rtld.c:544
#10 0x0000555555555438 in _start ()
```